# Exclude certain items from being added to a list with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am getting data from a Web Api and adding it to a list in my Windows store touch app with c#. I use the code below which works fine.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:12345/api/items");

var info = new List<SampleDataGroup>();


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

               var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);


                foreach (var data in item)
                {
                      var infoSect = new info
                            (

                                (string)data.Id.ToString(),
                                (string)data.Name,
                                (string)"",
                                (string)data.PhotoUrl,
                                (string)data.Description

                            );
                                 info.Add(infoSect);
                }
             }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error");
                await dlg.ShowAsync();
            }


            this.DefaultViewModel["Sections"] = info;
```

How do I check the data retrieved from the web api, to exclude items from the list whose `Name` contains the word "Test" in it. For example, an item with the `Name` "Soda Test" should not be included in the list.

So if Name contains "Test", do not add to list.

Comment: Have you tried using an IF statement before adding it to the list?

Comment: Your last line basically answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(!data.Name.ToString().Contains("Test"))
{
//Add Item to List
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = item.Where( d =>!d.Name.Contains("Test")).ToList();
items.ForEach(i => info.Add(new info(){
     data.Id.ToString(),
     ...

}));
```

Answer (score 2):

!you should be able to do this using Linq.

```
 info.AddRange(item.Where(i => !i.Name.Contains("Test"))
                    .Select(i => {
                    new info
                        (

                            (string)data.Id.ToString(),
                            (string)data.Name,
                            (string)"",
                            (string)data.PhotoUrl,
                            (string)data.Description

                        )}));
```

Comment: The question asked for "Contains" Test and select above is not populating the info list...

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content).Where(i=>!i.Name.Contains("Test"))
```